# Redirection with a wildcard

Tags: redirect, htaccess

I have put my wordpress installation liek these : http://www.mydomain.com/cms for the testing time, and time to implement thing in the database. Now i have switch the whole thing to : http://www.mydomain.com/ (root). How is it possible to tell all the request to /cms to be / (root). i know htaccess can do that, but i prefer a plugin

or how to migrate an installation from one directory to another seemlessly ?

Answer (score 1):

In your `wp-config.php` Just put this rule in there:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://www.yourdomain.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://www.yourdomain.com');
```

Put it right above:

```
/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */
```

Comment: Then I would go through with the search and replace plugin to search and replace all images and posts: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search-and-replace/

Comment: i wanna just make sure.... ANY request from : http://www.mydomain.com/cms like : http://www.mydomain.com/cms/paper01 will be redirected to http://www.mydomain.com/paper01... understand ?.. i just want the /cms to disapear ! and get the good page

Comment: oh, so you made mydomain.com/cms public to your viewers? I think you should be able to do a wildcard redirect within your hosting account. However, I am not sure.

Comment: Yep !, my fault... now google found a tons of pages at /cms/xyz that need to be silently redirected to /xyz !